# Servlet fails to update and returns a blank page

Tags: java, html, mysql, web

Am pretty new to programming in general and I have encountered a certain problem in my Java web app where my product information is not updating despite the adding and deleting of a product from the MySQL database working. When I hit submit on the update page the program would simply return me a blank page and the values would not update in the MySQL database.

Netbeans log and Apache tomcat logs are not returning error so I can only think that the redirection is going to a blank non-existing page instead but I have tried adding "../" to the form action but it did not work.

HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" action="product.update">
  <div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <!-- hidden form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.getID()}">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Product name" value="${product.getName()}" required />
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
      <input type="text" id="quantity" placeholder="Available quantity" value="${product.getProductQuantity()}" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
      <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Product price" value="${product.getPrice()}" required />
    </div>

    <!-- Break -->
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="primary" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Update product Servlet:

```
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String str_id=request.getParameter("id");
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String str_price=request.getParameter("price");
        String str_quantity=request.getParameter("quantity");
        
        ArrayList<String> errormsg=new ArrayList<>();
        boolean success=true;
        
        if(str_id==null || name==null || str_price==null || str_quantity==null){
            errormsg.add("Error: Null parameters.");
            success=false;
        }
        
        else if(str_id.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || str_price.isEmpty() || str_quantity.isEmpty()){
            errormsg.add("Error: Empty parameters.");
            success=false;
        }
        
        else{
            try{
                int id=Integer.parseInt(str_id);
                
                ProductDAO func=new ProductDAO();
                ProductBean bean=func.getProductByID(id);

                Double price=Double.parseDouble(str_price);
                int quantity=Integer.parseInt(str_quantity);
                
                success=func.updatePrice(bean, price) && func.updateName(bean, name) && func.updateStock(bean, quantity);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                success=false;
                errormsg.add("Error: IDs are not integers.");
            }
            
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/product/productupdate_success.jsp");
            if(success==false){
                rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/errors/error.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("error", errormsg);
            }
            
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

Product Bean class:

```
public class ProductBean implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int id;
    private Double price;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    
    public ProductBean(){
        this.id=-1;
        this.price=0.0;
        this.name="empty_noitem";
        this.quantity=0;
    }
    
    public ProductBean(int id, double prc, String nm, int qty){
        this.id=id;
        this.price=prc;
        this.name=nm;
        this.quantity=qty;
    }
    
    // setters
    public void updateID(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    
    public void updatePrice(double prc){
        this.price=prc;
    }
    
    public void updateName(String nm){
        this.name=nm;
    }
    
    public void updateProductQuantity(int qty){
        this.quantity=qty;
    }
    
    // getters
    public int getID(){
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public int getProductQuantity(){
        return this.quantity;
    }
}
```

Product DAO class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 *
 * @author SpicyAsh
 */
public class ProductDAO implements java.io.Serializable{
    private String driver;
    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
   
    private boolean loadClass(){
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public void loadSQL(){
        ResourceBundle sql=ResourceBundle.getBundle("system.sql.sql");
        this.url=sql.getString("url");
        this.user=sql.getString("user");
        this.pass=sql.getString("password");
        this.driver=sql.getString("driver");
    }  
    
    public ProductDAO(String driver, String url, String user, String pass)
    {
        this.url=url;
        this.user=user;
        this.pass=pass;
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public ProductDAO()
    {
        loadSQL();
    }
    
    public boolean exists(ProductBean bean){
        if(getProductByID(bean.getID())!=null || getProductByName(bean.getName())!=null){
            return true;
        }
        // else
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean addProduct(ProductBean bean){
        loadClass();
        String sql="insert into product(product_name, price, quantity) values(?,?,?)";
        boolean success=true;
        
        // writing try-catch like this automatically closes the resources
        // this is called try-with-resources
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps.setString(1, bean.getName());
            ps.setDouble(2, bean.getPrice());
            ps.setInt(3, bean.getProductQuantity());
            
            ps.executeUpdate();
            
            conn.commit();
        }
        
        catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    
    public ProductBean getProductByID(int inid){
        loadClass();
        String sql="select * from product where ID=?";
        ProductBean prod=new ProductBean();
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            
            ps.setInt(1, inid);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){                
                int id=rs.getInt("ID");
                String name=rs.getString("product_name");
                double price=rs.getDouble("price");
                int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                prod.updateID(id);
                prod.updateName(name);
                prod.updatePrice(price);
                prod.updateProductQuantity(quantity);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return prod;
    }
    
    public ProductBean getProductByName(String inname){
        loadClass();
        String sql="select * from product where product_name=?";
        ProductBean prod=new ProductBean();
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            
            ps.setString(1, inname);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                int id=rs.getInt("ID");
                String name=rs.getString("product_name");
                double price=rs.getDouble("price");
                int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                prod.updateID(id);
                prod.updateName(name);
                prod.updatePrice(price);
                prod.updateProductQuantity(quantity);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return prod;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<ProductBean> getAllProducts(){
        loadClass();
        String sql="select * from product";
        ProductBean bean=new ProductBean();
        ArrayList <ProductBean> arrList=new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                bean=new ProductBean();
                
                int id=rs.getInt("ID");
                String name=rs.getString("product_name");
                double price=rs.getDouble("price");
                int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                bean.updateID(id);
                bean.updateName(name);
                bean.updatePrice(price);
                bean.updateProductQuantity(quantity);
                
                arrList.add(bean);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return arrList;
    }
    
    // update methods
    public boolean updatePrice(ProductBean row, Double newPrice){
        if(!exists(row)){
            return false;
        }

        loadClass();
        boolean success=true;    
        String sql="update product set price=? where id=?";

        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps.setDouble(1, newPrice);
            ps.setInt(2, row.getID());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    // update methods
    public boolean updateName(ProductBean row, String newName){
        if(!exists(row)){
            return false;
        }

        loadClass();
        boolean success=true;
        String sql="update product set product_name=? where id=?";

        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps.setString(1, newName);
            ps.setInt(2, row.getID());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    public boolean updateStock(ProductBean row, int newStock){
        if(!exists(row)){
            return false;
        }

        loadClass();
        boolean success=true;    
        String sql="update product set quantity=? where id=?";

        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps.setInt(1, newStock);
            ps.setInt(2, row.getID());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    // delete method (ONLY ADMIN/OWNDER)
    public boolean removeProduct(ProductBean row){
        if(!exists(row)){
            return false;
        }
        
        loadClass();
        boolean success=true;
        String sql="delete from product where id=?";
        
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);){
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps.setInt(1,row.getID());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }
        
        catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
            e.printStackTrace();           
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

Product table structure in MySQL:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| product_name | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| price | double | YES |  | NULL |  |
| quantity | int | YES |  | 0 |  |

Comment: Rather than just `catch(SQLException e){
            success=false;
        }` - how about actually printing out the stacktrace?

Comment: Also I doubt that you need to prefcae your jsp pages with `WEB-INF`

Comment: Added the printing of the stacktrace but it failed to return anything so the url is not being accessed by the form properly.

Comment: If you are using an IDE why do you not debug your code and then maybe you will have a concrete problem.  Is the doPost (or similar) part of your servlet being entered into - what happens next?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider moving to Spring BOOT for MVC web apps and then use Spring Controllers and  ThymeLeaf for views. So much better then using older Servlets and JSP.  Start here:

https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-thymeleaf-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with the constructor. In there you have all the parameters and in the DAO Update you are missing the id.